# Bind Data From Microsoft Acess to Textbox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, textbox, ms-access-2007

I have a database named `PriceTesting` ( using Microsoft Access 2007 ) that contains a table named `tbl_dress` with columns:

```
Dress_ID, Dress_Name, Dress_Price
```

In the form, I have created a combobox and a text box.

So far I've succeeded binding the combobox with `Dress_Name` data using this code :-

```
Private Sub FillCombo()
        Try
            Dim fillcon As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\annonymous\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DressTest\DressTest\db\PriceTesting.accdb")
            Dim query As String = ("SELECT Dress_Name FROM tbl_dress")
            Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(query, fillcon)
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            da.Fill(ds)
            ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Dress_Name"
            ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("ERROR : " & ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

and it works... everytime the form loads, the combobox contains the data from `Dress_Name` column.

Now I want the `texbox.text = Dress_Price WHERE Dress_Name = combox.selecteditem`

any idea how to do that?
what I have in mind is only this : -

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

query = " SELECT Dress_Price FROM tbl_dress WHERE Dress_Name = ' " & Combobox1.Text & " ' "
Textbox1.text = query

End Sub
```

Comment: Besides, this question has nothing to do with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TRY THIS** and be sure to add **Dress_Price**"in your query

```
Private Sub FillCombo()
    Try
        Dim fillcon As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\annonymous\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DressTest\DressTest\db\PriceTesting.accdb")
        Dim query As String = ("SELECT Dress_Name, Dress_Price FROM tbl_dress")
        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(query, fillcon)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Dress_Name"
        ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0

        texbox.DataBindings.Clear()
        texbox.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables(0), "Dress_Price")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("ERROR : " & ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

**OR just change the code in your idea like this**  and be sure to add **Dress_Price**"in your query

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    dim dt as DataTable = Combobox1.DataSource
    dim dr as DataRow = dt.Rows(Combobox1.SelectedIndex)
    Textbox1.text = iif(dr.isNull("Dress_Price"), "", dr.isNull("Dress_Price").Tostring)
End Sub
```

Comment: it works.. thx a lot.. i will implement this in my actual project.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim fillcon As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\annonymous\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DressTest\DressTest\db\PriceTesting.accdb")
Dim query As String = " SELECT Dress_Price FROM tbl_dress WHERE Dress_Name = ' " & Combobox1.Text & "'" 
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(query, fillcon)
Dim dt As New DataTable
da.Fill(dt)
Textbox1.text = dt.rows(0).item(0)
```

Search for parameters to avoid sql injection. Also try to improve the query and use the ID instead of the dress_name

Comment: this is just a test form, and if it works i will implement the code in my actual project... i need to use the Dress_Name for the actual project..

" search for parameters to avoid sql injection " can u explain more about this... 

ive tried a code that uses excutescalar which ive found from google.. but its no working..

Comment: i got an eror : There is no row at position 0.